# Looping through two raster folders to perform raster calculation?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, raster-calculator, loop, con

I have two geodatabases with rasters containing information about "treecover" and "loss". The file names are slightly different but can be matched based on the last 8 characters (the coordinates of each raster granule).See image

I can perform this simple conditional statement using either CON or RASTER CALCULATOR to retrieve all "Loss" data situated on pixels which have a value for "treecover" greater than or equal to 50, with 9999 being assigned as the output value if the statement is FALSE. The output raster is exactly what I want. I just need to do it for 137 pairs of rasters

RASTER CALC STATEMENT: con("treecover raster" >= 50, "Loss raster", 9999)

I'm very much a beginner at using Python, but this is what I've managed to do so far based on similar questions posted here. Fair warning, I don't really know what some parts of the script do.

```
import arcpy, os, math

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")


CVR =
r"C:\Aquifer_recalc\Aquifer_recalc_NA\Treecover_NA\Treecover_Inputs.gdb"

LSS = r"C:\Aquifer_recalc\Aquifer_recalc_NA\Lossyear_NA\Lossyear_Inputs.gdb"


outws = r"C:\Aquifer_recalc\Aquifer_recalc_NA\ras_calc_con"


arcpy.env.workspace = CVR


rasterlist  = arcpy.ListRasters()


for r in rasterlist:
    r1 = arcpy.sa.Raster(r)
    r2 = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(LSS,r))

    result =  con(r1 >=50,r2,999)

    result.save(os.path.join(outws, r))
```

[image: The way I would like images to be paired]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arcpy.ListRasters()` function will give you a list with the filenames of all the rasters in a given workspace. This way, you can specify the first GDB as your workspace and get a list of all the rasters in it. Then, you can repeat this process for the second GDB.

```
CVR = r"C:\Aquifer_recalc\Aquifer_recalc_NA\Treecover_NA\Treecover_Inputs.gdb"
LSS = r"C:\Aquifer_recalc\Aquifer_recalc_NA\Lossyear_NA\Lossyear_Inputs.gdb"

# get first set of rasters
arcpy.env.workspace = CVR
cvr_rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

# get second set of rasters
arcpy.env.workspace = LSS
lss_rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
```

Because the order of your rasters match, you don't need to worry to order the rasters in a way pairs should match. This means the first name of `cvr_rasters` corresponds to the first name of `lss_rasters` (as they are sorted alphabetically). You can inspect these variables to make sure.

Having these two lists, you can take advantage of the `zip()` function, which will create a list of tuples for you to iterate through. The first tuple will have the first raster from `CVR` and the first raster from `LSS`, and so on. This way you can access two rasters at the same time:

```
for cvr_ras, lss_ras in zip(cvr_rasters, lss_rasters):
    r1 = arcpy.sa.Raster(cvr_ras)
    r2 = arcpy.sa.Raster(lss_ras)
    result = Con(r1 >=50, r2, 999)
    result.save(os.path.join(outws, cvr_ras))
```

Note that `Raster` is a class in `arcpy` that lets you create a `Raster` object from a raster file so you can perform raster calculator operations. It does not have anything to do with the name of your result. If you inspect either of `cvr_rasters` or `lss_rasters` you will see the oputput will be something like this:

`['Hansen_GFC2015_treecover2000_60N_160W', ...]`

This is a list containing one string for each raster you have in that GDB. However, you need something to tell `arcpy` you are dealing with rasters (hencer the `Raster` class). After this, you execute the `Con()` function and `arcpy` knows what you rasters actually are.

Regarding the name of the output, the `Con()` function returns a new `Raster` object. It has a `.save()` method that takes as a parameter the output name or path of the file. If you pass only a string and not a full path (*e.g.* `'my_raster'` instead of `r'C:\users\user01\my_raster.tif'`) it will try to save the raster in your current workspace. Right now, the name of one of your output file will be

`"C:\Aquifer_recalc\Aquifer_recalc_NA\ras_calc_conHansen_GFC2015_treecover2000__60N_160W"` or whatever numbers the first raster have. This is because it is joining `outws` with `cvr_ras` (which changes every iteration) using `os.path.join()`.

I recommend you to add the following line before the for loop:

`arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Aquifer_recalc\Aquifer_recalc_NA"`

And then add the following after `result = Con(r1 >=50, r2, 999)`

```
out_name = "loss_{}".format(cvr_ras[-8:])
result.save(out_name)
```

In the case of the example raster, out_name will be `"loss_60N_160W"` and will be stored in `C:\Aquifer_recalc\Aquifer_recalc_NA`. It will take the last 8 characters of the current value of `cvr_ras` every loop and use them to create the output file name. You can play around with the `out_name` variable to get different names if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm getting an error saying "NameError: name 'con' is not defined". Does 'con' even need to be defined since it's part of Raster calculator?

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice. You have to import it first. Write this line at the top of your script `from arcpy.sa import *` and change con for `Con`. Here is the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) with some examples .

Comment: I think that worked but I got another error,Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\Lib\ntpath.py", line 67, in join
    p_drive, p_path = splitdrive(p)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\Lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'Raster' has no len()

Comment: Check the edit. It's probably because I used a `Raster` object instead of a string as the name of the resulting raster. Now it will match the name of the corresponding cvr raster. You can change that, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this. Is a Raster object the automatic name given to a raster when you perform some sort of function? Does this mean I should change the cvr_ras and lss_ras names, or the cvr_rasters and lss_rasters?

Comment: I hope my edit answers your question.

Comment: It did I think we're almost there! I'm getting an error "Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to loss_50N_120W with output format GRID."

Comment: If your output workspace is a GDB, you don't have to specify an extension. However, in this case it is a normal folder. Simply add a `.tif` extension to the output name. `out_name = "loss_{}.tiff".format(cvr_ras[-8:])`

Comment: I think it worked! thank you so much for your patience you saved me a weekends worth of repetitive raster calculating!

Comment: Ok so something went wrong. I'm getting an error saying that the input raster does not exist. I think it has to do with my paths but i don't see anything wrong. I posted the question again with the updated script here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333082/looping-through-two-raster-folders-to-perform-raster-calculation-part-2